# Stripe integration with Polymer Starter Kit Plus

Tags: google-app-engine, polymer, stripe-payments, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have been playing around this sort of implementation but with no avail. Stripe with Polymer Starter Kit would be awesome! It's easy to create the token, I have done so [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qOrCq6xHl46XpjN2BwhK).

In Meteor, I'd have this code inside `Meteor.isServer`:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_***********************");

// (Assuming you're using express - expressjs.com)
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
var stripeToken = request.body.stripeToken;

var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
  currency: "usd",
  source: stripeToken,
  description: "Example charge"
}, function(err, charge) {
  if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
    // The card has been declined
  }
});
```

Since this question is only about [Polymer Starter Kit Plus](https://github.com/StartPolymer/polymer-starter-kit-plus), Is there a special place to have a server-side script to charge the token? I deploy to [gae](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/).